# Auth0 - Log into 2 apps in 1 tenant with different profiles

Tags: auth0

I have 2 React apps in 1 tenant, using `@auth0/auth0-react`. `App A` uses user/password to login, `App B` uses Google-OAuth-2. Both apps use the same auth0 audience & auth0 domain (and different clientIDs)

My workflow is:

- open 1st tab and log into `App A` with one profile
- open 2nd tab and log into `App B` with another profile
- open 3rd tab with `App A` again

The problem here is that I have to do the login process in `App A` again in the 3rd tab. In the 1st tab, I’m still logged in, but I’ll have to redo the login process if I refresh.

How can I decouple both login processes, so that I can only log once in each app without having them interfering with each other?